# Replace a character in java?

Tags: java

```
public void sendData(){
         try {
            URL data = new URL("http://mywebsite.net/isvalid.php?username=" + usernameField.getText() + "&password=" + passwordField.getText());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(data.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
             if(inputLine.length() > 0)
              inputString = inputLine;
                in.close();
            if(!inputString.equals("Incorrect password.")){
                System.out.println("Correct password");
                run();
                dispose();
            } else 
                if(usernameField.getText().length() > 0 && passwordField.getText().length() > 0) {
                invalidUP();
                System.out.println("Invalid username or password.");
                }  else
                    if(usernameField.getText().length() < 1 || (passwordField.getText().length() < 1)) {
                        System.out.println("No password or username entered.");
                        upLength();
            }
         } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
```

How would I check if usernameField or passwordField would have a space in it? And if it has, replace it with "_".

Also, if you think this method is wrong to send data or it can be done easier/quicker, please elaborate.

Comment: take a look at String.replace

Comment: Secret is in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Alright, sweet. I have used the replace method and it worked. Any opinions about the method itself (sendData)?

Comment: @user2192658 You are sending the username and password as it is. You can use some encryption algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Using [**String#replaceAll()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String uname ="abc xyz";
uname = uname.replaceAll("\\s+", "_");
```

Comment: Correct, but there is no need to take the huge RegExp gun out. `replace` should be much faster.

Comment: @mdsl notice my regex. this will replace multiple spaces with a `-`. i am assuming that OP need to replace multiple whitespaces with `-`

Comment: You should use "_"! Look at the question

Comment: Ah. Ok - if you think about tabs and what more, then Regexp might actually be better.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only space in your String  then try this:

```
username = username.replace(" " , "_");
```

Otherwise if  there are whitespace in your username then try this:

```
username = username.replaceAll("\\s+" , "_");
```

Comment: Why would you check if it contains a space? If it doesn't, `replace` won't do anything. Iterating over the string twice seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `String.replace`:

passwordField = passwordField.replace(' ', '_');

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.String has a nice method called [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).